# Airflow task concept: xcom and more or less and xcom pass

Tags: airflow, etl

I have some doubts. I use `sqlalchemy` in `SimpleHttpOperator.response_filter`: parsse and store to db. Next i need to retrieve specific table rows and save to file. I think also use `@task` with sqlalchemy: one point to retrieve and store. But there is `PostgresOperator`, which can be before the `@task`, and push the result by xcom, but seems it is not not effective. But if you stick to this concept It's clearer for a troubleshooting search and human view.

Now:

```
SimpleHttpOperator[parse and store to db] > @task[load and store to file]
```

Can be:

```
SimpleHttpOperator[parse] -> PostgresOperator[store] -> PostgresOperator[load] -> @task[store to local file]
```

What is better to use?